# Recursive PowerShell function fails to call itself

Tags: powershell, recursion, active-directory

I have been trying to create a script to map out an Active Directory's OU structures. (The end goal would be to have the equivalent of the windows `tree.com` command.)

For the following folder structure:

- Domain.local

  - Domain Controllers
  - Users

    - Internal
    - External

Would have the following Output:

```
[Domain.local]
Domain Controllers
Users
  Internal
  External
```

The code used to do it would be the following:

```
function Display-OU{
    param(
        [String]$ParentOU,
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$ChildOUs
    )
    # $ChildOUs
    $ChildOUs | ForEach-Object{$_.DN.Remove($_.Name)}
    if($ParentOU){
        $Spacing = "  "
    }else{
        $Spacing = ""
    }
    $Return = foreach($cOU in $ChildOUs){
        if($cOU.DN){
            Continue
        }
        $Parent = $cOU.Name
        "$Spacing$($cOU.Name)"
        $Children = $ChildOUs | Where-Object{$_.DN -contains $Parent}
        if($Children){
            "$Spacing$(Display-OU -ParentOU $ParentOU  -ChildOUs $Children)"
        }
    }
    return $Return
}

# Recover the OU data
$Raw = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | Select Name,DistinguishedName
# Clean up the data
$OUs = foreach($Entry in $Raw){
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Name = $Entry.Name
        Domain = ($Entry.DistinguishedName.Split(",") | Where-Object{$_ -match "DC="}) -join "." -replace "DC="
        DN = [System.Collections.ArrayList](($Entry.DistinguishedName -replace '\,DC=.+').Split(",") -replace "OU=")
    }
}

# Run the command depending on the number of domains
$Domains = $OUs.Domain | Select -Unique
foreach($D in $Domains){
    $dOUs = $OUs | Where-Object{$_.Domain -eq $D}
    Write-Host "[$D]"
    Display-OU -ChildOUs $dOUs
}
```

I am guessing I am doing something wrong when defining the variables, because I keep getting the following Output:

```
[testdomain.local]
Domain Controllers
Test_Domain_Users
```

As far as I understand, it runs the first time but fails to call itself again...

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger. Single-step through the code, observe variable values and check if they meet your assumptions. E. g. is the `$Children` variable not empty. VSCode with the PowerShell extension provides a really nice debugging experience.

Comment: @zett42, I have already tried doing so. When running the contents of the function run manually, it still fails to call `Display-OU -ParentOU $Parent -ChildOUs $Children`. Despite confirming that both variables `$Parent` and `$Children` are populated.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quite fun exercise, I can show you how I would do it with a [`Stack<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-7.0) instead of recursion and a custom [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2). Most of the logic is re-used from [this module](https://github.com/santisq/PSTree).

```bash
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
using namespace Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management
using namespace System.Management.Automation

function Get-TreeOrganizationalUnit {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Identity,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $IncludeContainer
    )

    end {
        $filter = "(|(name=$Identity)(samAccountName=$Identity)(distinguishedName=$Identity))"
        $object = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $filter

        if(-not $object) {
            return $PSCmdlet.WriteWarning("Cannot find an object with Identity: '$Identity'.")
        }

        if($object.Count -gt 1) {
            $errorRecord = [ErrorRecord]::new(
                [Exception] "More than one object found with Identity: '$Identity'. Please use 'DistinguishedName' attribute.",
                [string] "AmbiguousResult",
                [ErrorCategory]::NotImplemented,
                $Identity
            )
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($errorRecord)
        }

        class Tree {
            [string] $Hierarchy
            [string] $ObjectClass
            hidden [int] $Depth
            hidden [string] $Base

            Tree([ADObject] $Object, [int] $Depth) {
                $this.Hierarchy   = [Tree]::Indent($Object.Name, $Depth)
                $this.ObjectClass = $Object.ObjectClass
                $this.Base        = $Object.DistinguishedName
                $this.Depth       = $Depth
            }

            static [string] Indent([string] $String, [Int64] $Indentation) {
                return "$('    ' * $Indentation)$String"
            }

            static [void] DrawTree([object[]] $InputObject, [PSCmdlet] $Cmdlet) {
                $corner, $horizontal, $pipe, $connector = '└', '─', '│', '├'

                $cornerConnector = "${corner}$(${horizontal}*2) "
                foreach($group in $InputObject | Group-Object Depth | Select-Object -Skip 1) {
                    foreach($item in $group.Group) {
                        $item.Hierarchy = $item.Hierarchy -replace '\s{4}(?=\S)', $cornerConnector
                    }
                }

                for($i = 1; $i -lt $InputObject.Count; $i++) {
                    $index = $InputObject[$i].Hierarchy.IndexOf($corner)
                    if($index -ge 0) {
                        $z = $i - 1
                        while($InputObject[$z].Hierarchy[$index] -notmatch "$corner|\S") {
                            $replace = $InputObject[$z].Hierarchy.ToCharArray()
                            $replace[$Index] = $pipe
                            $InputObject[$z].Hierarchy = [string]::new($replace)
                            $z--
                        }

                        if($InputObject[$z].Hierarchy[$index] -eq $corner) {
                            $replace = $InputObject[$z].Hierarchy.ToCharArray()
                            $replace[$Index] = $connector
                            $InputObject[$z].Hierarchy = [string]::new($replace)
                        }
                    }
                }
                $Cmdlet.WriteObject($InputObject, $true)
            }
        }

        $stack = [Stack[Tree]]::new()
        $stack.Push([Tree]::new($object, 0))

        $param = @{
            LDAPFilter  = '(objectClass=organizationalUnit)'
            SearchScope = 'OneLevel'
        }

        if($IncludeContainer.IsPresent) {
            $param['LDAPFilter'] = '(|(objectClass=container)' + $param['LDAPFilter'] + ')'
        }

        [Tree]::DrawTree(@(
            while($stack.Count) {
                $target = $stack.Pop()
                $target
                $param['SearchBase'] = $target.Base
                foreach($object in Get-ADObject @param) {
                    $stack.Push([Tree]::new($object, $target.Depth + 1))
                }
            }
        ), $PSCmdlet)
    }
}
```

The usage is straight forward, the `-Identity` can be either the `SamAccountName` or `DistinguishedName` attribute of the initial object (the object that is used as base):

```bash
# Only OrganizationalUnits
Get-TreeOrganizationalUnit -Identity myDomain

# Includes Containers too
Get-TreeOrganizationalUnit -Identity myDomain -IncludeContainer
```

Output would look something like this:

```
Hierarchy              ObjectClass
---------              -----------
myDomain               domainDNS
├── Workstations       organizationalUnit
├── SomeOU             organizationalUnit
│   ├── OtherOU1       organizationalUnit
│   └── OtherOU2       organizationalUnit
├── TestOU             organizationalUnit
├── People             organizationalUnit
├── Operations         organizationalUnit
└── Domain Controllers organizationalUnit
```

Comment: First, great script, does exactly what I intended to do. But I have to admit I am a bit lost when reading it. Is this still PowerShell or is it C#?
And although you did give me a solution for visualizing the architecture of an Active Directory, I don't know if I can mark it as an answer to the given question...

Comment: @AlD.J. I know, the code is not easy to follow, 100% understandable, but it's also hard to explain. I'm fine you decide not to accept it, my intent from the beginning was to share a different approach, I don't like recursion when it can be avoided (it's pretty slow). This is PowerShell btw, tho it can look similar to C# when it comes to classes :P